# Gracefully reloading gunicorn after switching the current symlink to a new directory

Tags: python, deployment, reload, symlink, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my application and my folders is organised in a way which means I only change the symlink when I want to deploy a new version. Like this:

```
./2013-07-16-10-12-48-test/  
./2013-07-16-10-17-01-test/  
./current -> 2013-07-16-10-17-01-test/
```

Normally I'd simply use `kill -HUP master-pid` and everything works as long as the directory remains the same. But when I first change the symlink and then reload the code is still running from the old directory through its absolute path, like gunicorn is following the symlink and saving the final path.
I start gunicorn like this: `gunicorn run:app -c gunicorn-config.py` inside the "current" directory and my configuration file looks like this:

```
workers = 4
worker_class = 'gevent'
bind = '127.0.0.1:5000'
pidfile = '/var/run/gunicorn.pid'
debug = False
loglevel = 'debug'
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn-error.log'
daemon = True
```

Is there a way for gunicorn to re-evaluate the symlink or only save the symlink instead of the full path? Maybe in some kind of `on_starting` or `on_reload` hook?

[Here's](http://wingu.github.io/zero-downtime-gunicorn.html) a solution I couldn't get to work, maybe that gives some more context.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?  Also the link you provided is broken.

Comment: @AJP: I'll add my solution as a reply below =)

Comment: Oh, and the link works for me, weird..

Comment: Huh, it's working again!  Thanks for the fast response @moodh !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by using the [USR2 signal](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/signals.html).
This is my init.d file, and after a deploy I'll just run `service gunicorn start_or_reload` which either starts or gracefully reloads the code based on the new location. It technically spawns another master inside the current master, then kills off the old workers and master and finally promotes the newly spawned master. I went with this solution to later add smoke tests before killing off the old master and things like that. I hope this helps someone!

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          thin
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      S 0 1 6
# Short-Description: thin initscript
# Description:       thin
### END INIT INFO

# Original author: Forrest Robertson

# Do NOT "set -e"

DEPLOY_PATH=/opt/project/current
PID_FOLDER=/var/run/gunicorn
PID_FILE=$PID_FOLDER/project.pid
OLD_PID_FILE=$PID_FOLDER/project.pid.oldbin

start() {
    cd $DEPLOY_PATH && gunicorn run:app -c gunicorn-config.py
}

stop() {
  if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
  then
    kill `cat $PID_FILE`
    rm $PID_FILE
  fi
}

reload() {
    kill -USR2 `cat $PID_FILE`
    sleep 1
    kill -QUIT `cat $OLD_PID_FILE`
    rm $OLD_PID_FILE
}

start_or_reload() {
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
    then
        reload
    else
        start
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting server..."
        start
    ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading server..."
        reload
    ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping server..."
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        echo "Restarting server..."
        stop && sleep 1 && start
    ;;
    start_or_reload)
        echo 'Starting or reloading server...'
        start_or_reload
    ;;
    wup)
        echo "Increasing workers..."
        kill -TTIN `cat $PID_FILE`
    ;;
    wdown)
        echo "Decreasing workers..."
        kill kill -TTOU `cat $PID_FILE`
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME {start|reload|stop|restart|start_or_reload|wup|wdown}" >&2
        exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```